# Finding biggest number from text file contaning two columns and several rows

Tags: bash

For example, I have got a text file containing 2 columns:

```
    0.000000e+00        0.000000e+00
    1.958870e-02        1.566242e-02
    3.923750e-02        6.509739e-03
    4.394830e-01        3.216723e-03
    4.594830e-01        2.508868e-03
    4.794890e-01        3.813512e-04
    4.995070e-01        8.846235e-04
    5.997070e-01        1.671057e-03
```

I want to find maximum values in column 2 which shows corresponding value of column 1 in the output.

Comment: Please try to be more clear about what you want to achieve, provide an expected output from the 3 rows you showed, and show us what you tried so far.

Comment: how can a text file contain columns?

Comment: What is your specific problem?

Comment: its a .dat file and contains the data extracted from the graph. basically i want to find peak value of the graph plotted betwwen x and y axis .corresponding datas are obtained in .dat file from the tool

Comment: So `sort -k2n file.dat | tail -1` would find your max? and `sort -k2nr file.dat | tail -1` the min ?

Comment: thanks guys but its not giving exact values

Comment: its giving another value which is not maximum in this case

Comment: Please, edit your question with a sample of few lines of the dat file, and what output do you expect from it, or you'll never get an answer.

Comment: @jeanrjc , please have a look now . i guess now you can understand my problem

Comment: @sumitsharma : Ok, I answered

Answer (score 1):

this awk one-liner will do it without sorting:

```
awk '$2>m{f=$1;m=$2}END{print f}' file
```

it outputs:

```
1.958870e-02
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just testing the exact same solution that @jeanrjc just posted as a comment - I think, if I understand your question, it is the correct answer (to get the MAX row):

`sort -n -k2 file.dat | tail -1`

Answer (score 0):

If you have `1e-2` notation, you need to sort with `-g` option :

Max :

```
sort -k2g file.dat | tail -1
```

Min :

```
sort -k2gr file.dat | tail -1
```

- `-k2` stands for column 2
- `-r` (or `-k2r`) for reverse order

if you have a header you can remove it with awk :

```
awk 'NR>1' file.dat | sort -k2g | tail -1
```

You can alternatively use `head` instead of `tail` to get opposite result, eg :

```
sort -k2g file.dat | head -1
```

will give you the min

Hope this helps.